# Initialization of vector<unique_ptr> fails with copy error

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, unique-ptr

I'm struggeling to properly initialize a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`'s.

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base{
    public:
        std::string getString() { return this->string; };
    protected:
        std::string string;
};
class Derived: public Base{
    public:
        Derived(std::string bla){
            this->string = bla;
    }
};
class Collection{
    protected:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> mappings;
};
class DerivedCollection: public Collection{
    public:
        DerivedCollection(std::string bla){
            std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> maps;
            maps.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>(bla));
            //or this: (does not work aswell)
            //maps.emplace_back(new Derived(bla));
            this->mappings = maps;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    DerivedCollection test = DerivedCollection("bla");
    return 0;
}
```

Somehow only defining `mappings`  triggers the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: 
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Base; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base>]’
 { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Which tells me that I somehow manage to construct a unique_ptr from a const unique_ptr, which does not work since unique_ptr is not copy-constructable.

Somehow this still fails even if I comment everything inside of the `DerivedCollection` constructor.

My guess is that I need a proper constructor for the `Collection` class. Im not sure howto define it though.

Any Ideas?

-- malte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`maps` is non-copyable, as it's a `vector` of `unique_ptr`. Moving it into `mappings` solves the issue:

```
this->mappings = std::move(maps);
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A9PvZKp8rHoWa7vt)

---

Your code has other issues as well:

- You should use the *member initialization list* to initialize data members instead of the *constructor body*.
- `getString` could return `const std::string&` to avoid a copy.
- `Derived`'s constructor could `std::move` `bla` into the data member.
- `test` could be initialized as follows: `DerivedCollection test{"bla"}`.
- `new` should never be used - use `make_unique` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, `std:swap(mappings, maps)`

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Regarding the other issues: This is just a quick example i put together in about 30 seconds, so that might explain the sloppy style. Furthermore this problem popped up in a context where I needed non-trivial constructor logic, thats why i didn't use the initilization list. Thanks for the tips though!